String codification UTF-8 to get 1 Byte
I have a problem when I try to write String in a file. For example, I have this code to convert an Integer value to a 2-byte String but the String codification convert Integer to invisible bytes.
I need to convert, for example, 45557 integer number on 2 bytes 0xB1 and 0xF5 and convert it to String õ±. Then, in other processes, decoding õ± to get B1F5.
The problem is when I try decode õ±, I get C3B5C2B1. I know it is a problem of String codification but how can I solve it?
I'm trying this:
int iInteger = 45557;
        
int iLow    =  iInteger & 0b0000000011111111;
int iHight  = (iInteger & 0b1111111100000000)>>8;
        
file_raw.open_file();
        
file_raw.println (" Character 1 num: " + iLow);
file_raw.println (" Character 2 num:" + iHight);
        
String cLow = new Character((char) 245).toString();
String cHigh = new Character((char) 177).toString();

Then the result is:
Character 1 num: 245
Character 2 num:177
Character 1 string: õ
Character 2 string :±

To your eyes they are good but when I am going to decode those characters to HEX I get 16-bit values because the coding is in UTF-8:
õ -> C3B5 (conversion on notepad++ or internet converters)
± -> C2B1

Just I want:
õ -> F5
± -> B1


If you are defining a number in a 2 byte format, there is no point trying or expecting that those codes are valid in some encoding which can be converted a String.

If you write a String to a file, there is an encoding involved - either specified explicitly or the default encoding (which seems to be UTF-8 in your case). I have no idea what file_raw is, but that seems to be encoding the Strings into bytes as UTF-8, so you will need to change the way you create file_raw to make it use ISO-8859-1.

So what you have done is to encode õ and ± in UTF-8.  You can confirm this with your favorite online Unicode -> UTF-8 converter. You actually need to write the bytes as-is ... without transcoding into UTF-8.

You don't want UTF-8, you want one of the iso-8859 variants.

If Character.isDefined(iInteger); you could write it out as is, but there's no guarantee that would return true, and that situation won't necessarily be helped by splitting it in half. As has been said, treating binary data as strings is not a good idea. You could of course hex-encode of base64-encode it

You should work directly with raw byte arrays and avoid converting them to String in the middle, as String uses UTF-16 internally in Java, which causes encoding issues.
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ByteFileExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iInteger = 45557;

        byte iLow = (byte) (iInteger & 0xFF); // Low byte (F5)
        byte iHigh = (byte) ((iInteger >> 8) & 0xFF); // High byte (B1)

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.bin")) {
            fos.write(iHigh); // Write the high byte (B1)
            fos.write(iLow);  // Write the low byte (F5)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("output.bin")) {
            int high = fis.read(); // Read the high byte (B1)
            int low = fis.read();  // Read the low byte (F5)

            // Combine the two bytes into an integer
            int result = (high << 8) | (low & 0xFF);

            System.out.println("Decoded integer: " + result); // Output 45557
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


ints are four bytes wide, not two

int in Java is a 32-bit integer. 32/8 = 4 octets.
